# Finding Network Analyst tools in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: network-analyst, arcgis-pro

I am trying to run some network analysis within 3D buildings to study handicap accessibility, best routes, emergency evacuation routes, etc. In ArcMap 10.3 there is a simple and easy to use toolbar that allows you to run the network analysis "on the fly" (directly to the map) and it is very quick to reset the start and end paths, restrictions, barriers, etc. With ArcGIS Pro so far I am able to run the network analysis, but it is very slow and requires individual inputs and outputs to be ran one at a time. With a large amount of starting and destination nodes this can be very tedious.

I was wondering if there is any way to get ArcGIS Pro to run the network analyst similar to the ArcMap 10.3 toolbar, or if there were any other options that can be used within ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a [Network Analyst](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/what-is-network-analyst-.htm) license for testing but I can see a button for it on the ANALYSIS tab of the ribbon:

[image]

If this does not lead to the options that you seek, then I think you should consider posting an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com).