# Is there a way to bring ArcGIS 10.3 tools/toolbars into ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, toolbar, arcgis-pro

I am currently working on a project that involves using Network Analyst, and I really dislike the way that it is set up in ArcGIS Pro vs. the toolbar from ArcGIS 10.3. I was wondering if there is any way that I can incorporate the ArcGIS 10.3 Network Analyst Toolbar, as well as any other tools/toolbars into ArcGIS Pro. If this requires using Python I am a little new to it, but exposed to say the least and willing to use it as a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use ArcGIS Pro instead of ArcMap + Network Analyst? If the tools work well in the old environment, why not just use them there?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be a follow on from [Finding Network Analyst tools in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154834/arcgis-10-3-toolbar-equivalent-for-network-analyst-in-arcgis-pro)

There is some documentation on [Python migration for ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/python-migration-for-arcgis-pro.htm) but I think it will be unlikely to help you with what you are trying to do here.

The best advice that I can offer is to try and document particular workflows that you currently perform using the Network Analyst toolbar in the ArcGIS 10.x architecture and then ask how the same can be done using ArcGIS Pro.

If you find that they cannot be done, or doing them is far more cumbersome in ArcGIS Pro than it was in ArcMap, then that should make very useful [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com).

I have somewhat similar problems trying to reproduce ArcGIS 10.x workflows that use Python AddIns in ArcGIS Pro and the above is the approach that I am taking.